# How to extract json var with Groovy and JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Calling a REST API with JMeter 3.3, I have following JSON response:

```
{"map":{},"meta":{"code":"123"}}
```

How can I extract the value of code (123)?

So far I am using this:

- Thread Group
- HTTP Request
- JSON Extractor

with this 2 vars: `code; meta`
and this json path expressions: `$.code; $.meta`

- JSR223 Assertion

with this Groovy code:

```
String codeString =  vars.get("code");

String meta =  vars.get("meta");

log.info ("The code answer is " + codeString);  

if (codeString != "000"){
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("The code is: " + codeString + " - meta is: " + meta);

        AssertionResult.setFailure(true); 
}
```

this is the assertion result instead:

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: The code is: No_Default - meta is: {"code":"000"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in JSON path expression `$.code` for getting code, it's under second hierarchy and therefore you are missing `.`, use the following:

```
$..code
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JsonSlurper` to extract the data you are interested in:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String json = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

def root = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def code = root.meta.code
```

Answer (score 3):

Given you use Groovy you don't need the JSON Path Extractor, you can validate your `code` like:

```
def code = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..code').get(0).toString()
if (!code.equals('000')) {
     AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
     AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('The code is ' + code)
}
```

More information:

- [Jayway Json Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)